# How can i make popup colorbox height responsive

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, colorbox

I need some help with a colorbox height that I want to make responsive. So far I found many suggestions on the internet but none of them can be adjusted to solve my case. So i need some expert advice. Here is the colorbox jquery I have:

```
function callappropiate(id,userid,usertype)
{    
    var popupvar    = jQuery.noConflict();      

        popupvar('#msgid').val(id);
        popupvar('#titleContainer2').css('display','block');            
        popupvar.colorbox({ 
            opacity:0.4,
            inline:true, 
            innerWidth:550, 
            innerHeight:220,
            href:"#popDiv2"
        });
}
```

Below is the HTML I use:

```
<div id="popDiv2" style='display:inline;'>
    <div id="titleContainer2">
        <div class="form_fields_pop_up">
            //Some HTML HERE
        </div>               
    </div>          
</div>
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: how about instead of passing `innerWidth` and `innerHeight` from JS, set it up on CSS using the selector for your `#popDiv2` ? That way, you can handle media queries or even use percentage based dimensions to achieve  responsiveness.

Comment: @TheWarlock, that's the thing, I cannot set customized CSS for #popDiv2. It only works for form_fields_pop_up, which is actually the content inside the container but not the container height/width itself.

Comment: can i see the thing via a url?

Comment: I managed to fix it by adding CSS to `form_fields_pop_up` instead of `#popDiv2` and setting `innerWidth:false`, `innerHeight:false`.

Comment: So CSS was the answer :)